# Can SOLR faceted result using sum function be further filtered on the server

Tags: solr

In SOLR version 6.0.0, can faceted result be further filtered before the response is returned to the client? My uses case uses the facet "sum" function to calculate the aggregate deposit for each customer. So far so good.

I would like to filter the rows returned in the facet response to only show me those customers who have deposited above a certain threshold. I can't seem to find a way to do that. Is it possible?

I am trying to avoid processing the response after it returns from the SOLR server. I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish this on the server side. The reason I am trying to do this is on the server side is that the data set might be very large. If I did this on the client side, I might need to do many faceted searches with the 'limit' and 'offset' parameters to find the location of my threshold. Once found continue with use case.

References consulted:
http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/

Below is what I did to setup the environment.

1. Created a csv file named entry.csv with the following data

   ```
   id,name_s,date_dt,flow_s,amount_f
   1,John,2016-01-01T00:00:00Z,Deposit,10
   2,Mary,2016-01-15T00:00:00Z,Deposit,20
   3,Peter,2016-01-19T00:00:00Z,Deposit,30
   4,John,2016-01-20T00:00:00Z,Deposit,40
   5,Mary,2016-01-22T00:00:00Z,Deposit,50
   6,Mary,2016-01-23T00:00:00Z,Deposit,60
   ```
2. Start the SOLR server

   ```
   $ bin/solr start
   ```
3. Create a new core named simple.

   ```
   $ bin/solr create -c simple
   ```
4. Import the data

   ```
   $ bin/post -c simple ~/entry.csv
   ```
5. Query the data to validate import was successful

   ```
   $ curl -s http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json
   {
     "responseHeader":{
       "status":0,
       "QTime":0,
       "params":{
         "q":"*:*",
         "indent":"on",
         "wt":"json"}},
     "response":{"numFound":6,"start":0,"docs":[
         {
           "id":"1",
           "name_s":"John",
           "date_dt":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
           "flow_s":"Deposit",
           "amount_f":10.0,
           "_version_":1532465926194069504},
         {
           "id":"2",
           "name_s":"Mary",
           "date_dt":"2016-01-15T00:00:00Z",
           "flow_s":"Deposit",
           "amount_f":20.0,
           "_version_":1532465926248595456},
         {
           "id":"3",
           "name_s":"Peter",
           "date_dt":"2016-01-19T00:00:00Z",
           "flow_s":"Deposit",
           "amount_f":30.0,
           "_version_":1532465926250692608},
         {
           "id":"4",
           "name_s":"John",
           "date_dt":"2016-01-20T00:00:00Z",
           "flow_s":"Deposit",
           "amount_f":40.0,
           "_version_":1532465926252789760},
         {
           "id":"5",
           "name_s":"Mary",
           "date_dt":"2016-01-22T00:00:00Z",
           "flow_s":"Deposit",
           "amount_f":50.0,
           "_version_":1532465926253838336},
         {
   me_s":"Mary",
           "date_dt":"2016-01-23T00:00:00Z",
           "flow_s":"Deposit",
           "amount_f":60.0,
           "_version_":1532465926255935488}]
     }}
   ```
6. Query the data with a facet showing the total gross deposit amount for each customer.

   ```
   $ curl -s http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select -d 'q=*:*&rows=0&
   json.facet={
     customers:{
      type:terms,
      field:name_s,
      sort:{gross:desc},
      facet:{
        gross:"sum(amount_f)"
      }
     }
   }

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <response>
     <lst name="responseHeader">
       <int name="status">0</int>
       <int name="QTime">1</int>
       <lst name="params">
         <str name="q">*:*</str>
         <str name="json.facet">{   customers:{    type:terms,    field:name_s,    sort:{gross:desc},    facet:{      gross:"sum(amount_
         <str name="rows">0</str>
       </lst>
     </lst>
     <result name="response" numFound="6" start="0"/>
     <lst name="facets">
       <int name="count">6</int>
       <lst name="customers">
         <arr name="buckets">
           <lst>
             <str name="val">Mary</str>
             <int name="count">3</int>
             <double name="gross">130.0</double>
           </lst>
           <lst>
             <str name="val">John</str>
             <int name="count">2</int>
             <double name="gross">50.0</double>
           </lst>
           <lst>
             <str name="val">Peter</str>
             <int name="count">1</int>
             <double name="gross">30.0</double>
           </lst>
         </arr>
       </lst>
     </lst>
   </response>
   ```
7. What I would like to achieve

I would like to filter only those customers that had deposited more than 100 dollars. That would mean that in the response, I would like to see only Mary who has an aggregate deposit of 130. I don't want to see John or Peter returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 6.3.0 of Apache SOLR cloud, there is a built in "/sql" handler. Please see the apache's wiki page at the URL below on the details of the handler.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parallel+SQL+Interface#ParallelSQLInterface-/sqlRequestHandler

To achieve a result for #7 of the question, the following query can be submitted and the result will only show names and total aggregate amount if they are above 100

```
stmt=SELECT name_s, sum(amount_f) as total
FROM simple
GROUP BY name_s
HAVING total > 100
ORDER BY total desc
```

In my local environment, SOLR cloud is hosted on ip 10.0.0.40 and port 8983 and I had created a collection name 'simple.'

```
curl --data-urlencode 'stmt=SELECT name_s, sum(amount_f) as total FROM simple GROUP BY name_s HAVING total>100 ORDER BY total desc' http://10.0.0.40:8983/solr/simple/sql


{"result-set":{"docs":[
{"name_s":"Mary","total":130.0},
{"EOF":true,"RESPONSE_TIME":7}]}}
```